# I cannot understand an error message in RStudio: error in `data_frame()`: ! Can't recycle `..1` (size 3339) to match `PANEL` (size 0)

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel

I am very new to R and I am struggling to interpret an error message.
I'm trying to plot a bar graph using two variables from my data frame with the ggplot function, but I keep getting this error message:

Error in `data_frame()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 3339) to match `PANEL` (size 0).
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

What does it mean? I don't understand what `..1` is, and what it means by `PANEL` (size 0).

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset and all the relevant code, in a plain text format.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.